Running command with pipe and spaces on PowerShell using `wsl`
On a PowerShell (7), one can run a Linux command using: wsl grep 'test'.
How can I run a more complicated command that involves piping (on Linux/WSL) and spaces?
For example:
wsl find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep 'main('

This results in an error:
xargs: The term 'xargs' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

even though xargs is obviously available inside WSL.
Variations of this like putting another wsl in front of xargs result in this error:
wsl find . -name '*.txt' | wsl xargs grep 'main('
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `xargs grep main('
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'wsl.exe' failed to run: The pipe is being closed.At line:1 char:1
+ wsl find . -name '*.txt' | wsl xargs grep 'main('
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.

Note that I want to do this from a PowerShell directly, not first launch a WSL terminal, then run the Linux command within that (which obviously works).

wsl find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep 'main(' runs find . -name '*.txt' inside wsl then pipe the result to xargs in the current shell, which is outside wsl so obviously it can't be run if xargs is not available in the host environment. You have to run the whole pipeline inside wsl:
wsl sh -c "find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep 'main('"

But you'll need to adjust -n and other arguments if required to make it more efficient. Or if your files contain no space or newlines then you can simply pass the whole result to grep like this so that grep runs only once
wsl sh -c 'grep "main(" $(find /your/path -name "*.txt")'

You can also run the pipeline in PowerShell like this
$ wsl find . -name '*.txt' | Get-ChildItem | Select-String -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch 'main('"
$ wsl find . -name '*.txt' | gci | sls -Ca -S 'main('"
$ Select-String -Path $(wsl find . -name '*.txt') -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch 'main('"
$ sls -Path $(wsl find . -name '*.txt') -Ca -S 'main('"

Or doing everything from PowerShell without going through wsl
$ Get-ChildItem -Recurse '\\wsl$\your\path\' | Select-String -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch 'main('"
$ gci -s '\\wsl$\your\path\' | sls -Ca -S 'main('"

Or if the file doesn't need to be recursively searched then this will work
Select-String -Path \\wsl$\your\path\*.txt -SimpleMatch 'main('


Thanks! My problem is that I can type find ... | xargs grep '...' from memory without thinking about it, but add any complexity to that (like $(...) or PowerShell commands - which are a whole new "language") and I have to look it up every time, making me inefficient. Given that, I think  the command you posted with wsl sh -c "..." fits the bill, I can probably just about remember/learn that.
I don't quite understand, what do you mean with I'll have to adjust -n - I can't see a -n parameter anywhere, is that -name, and what does that have to do with spaces or newlines inside files?

@Ela782 phuclv meant -n argument of xargs. And spaces/white characters in filenames is a separate matter and it always relevant to correct usage of xargs (you should really use -print0 in find and -0 in xargs to be safe).

@Ela782 grep file-by-file is inefficient, therefore you need xargs to pass multiple files at once with -n, and indeed you should use -0 to make it work with any files
